# how to load a image on windows and linux

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a python script that needs to run on Windows and linux. I am using pygames's image.load function.

Google told me to do `pygame.image.load('.\\files\\thumbnale.png')`, but that gave me this error

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open .\files\thumbnale.png
```

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try importing OS and doing this:

```
pygame.image.load(os.path.join('files', 'thumbnale.png'))
```

If that does not work, try this:

```
pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'files', 'thumbnale.png'))
```

If even that does not work, then check the names of your folders and/or files to see if you are mispelling filenames or directories.